# Postfix store emails

Tags: postfix

Is it possible to store email message before every check?\
I use postfix -> amavis -> spammassassin -> av
So on spamasasin level there no problem, but on when postfix receive message it can reject it by different filter such as `reject_unauth_destination` `reject_invalid_helo_hostname` and others.

Some mails rejected using blacklists. I use `check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/access_client` but access client stores only email addresses and not server hosts.

Comment: What are you asking? The email is stored in the queue while it is passed between those programs and postfix, and until it is delivered to its final destination.

Comment: Why do you want the messages which you rejected? Most of the smtpd_*_restrictions will reject even before postfix completely receives the mail and so it will not be possible to get such messages.

Answer (score 0):

You better use a System like http://www.magicvillage.de/~Fritz_Borgstedt/assp/0003D91C-8000001C/

This system keep a copy of inbound and outbound email for bayesian spam filter training data.